# Is it possible to RECEIVE job applications through the LinkedIn API?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I see LinkedIn documentation on how to post job, apply for jobs, and search jobs. But I'm curious if it's possible to post a job on LinkedIn normally and then **receive** an API notification when people apply to it. In other words, I want to integrate with the application rather then the job posting. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any way to download the users record who had apply for specific job through API call. I'm looking for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you want to integrate the job applications you receive with your own Applicant Tracking System. Check the [processing job applications developer documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/apply-processing-applications) for more details.

Comment: That's interesting but it appears to only apply when using the one-click apply widget. I'm trying do this same thing but from normal applications submitted through LinkedIn.com

Comment: @Samer: Above link is broken now. Is there any API to get the list of users who had apply for the job.

Comment: The linkedin API documentation seems to be a mess. Is this still possible?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-connect/receive-applications

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It looks like documentation moved to microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-connect/receive-applications

Essentially you create a webhook and register it with the job post. Then linkedin will POST the job application to that hook.

```
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"X-LI-Signature":"d3756e445a8065c0f38c2182c502f8229800eb2c6a9f3b4a1fdf152af867e6fc",
"Content-Length":"107",
"Connection":"Keep-Alive",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate"

{
  "type": "JOB_APPLICATION_EXPORT",
  "externalJobId": "jobIdOnAtsPartner",
  "jobApplicationId": "urn:li:jobApplication:12345678",
  "jobApplicant": "urn:li:person:abc123",
  "appliedAt": 1602137400011,
  "applicantSkills": [
    {
      "skillUrn": "urn:li:skill:12345",
      "skillName": "Java",
      "jobMatched": true,
      "assessmentVerified": true
    }
  ],
  "questionResponses": {
    "resumeQuestionResponses":
        {"resumeQuestionAnswer":
            {"mediaUrl":"https://www.linkedin.com/ambry/?x-li-ambry-ep=AQFBV...",
            "mediaUrn":"urn:li:media:AgAAA..."}​
      },
    "contactInformationQuestionResponses": {
      "firstNameAnswer": {
        "value": "First"
      },
      "lastNameAnswer": {
        "value": "Last"
      },
      "emailAnswer": {
        "value": "applicant@linkedin.com"
      }
    },
    "voluntarySelfIdentificationQuestionResponses": {
      "disabilityAnswer": "NO",
      "genderAnswer": "MALE",
      "raceAnswer": "ASIAN",
      "veteranStatusAnswer": "NOT_PROTECTED_VETERAN"
    },
    "educationQuestionResponses": {
      "educationExperienceQuestionSetResponses": [
        {
          "school": {
            "value": "UC Berkeley"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "workQuestionResponses": {
      "workExperienceQuestionSetResponses": [
        {
          "company": {
            "value": "LinkedIn"
          },
          "title": {
            "value": "Software Engineer"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "additionalQuestionResponses": {
      "customQuestionSetResponses": [
        {
          "customQuestionResponses": [
            {
              "questionIdentifier": "question1",
              "answer": {
                "multipleChoiceAnswerValue": {
                  "symbolicNames": [
                    "right"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```